# How do you not to repeat code in a powershell module? For example, getting a list of hostnames from a file, or storing user credentials

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell module with a list of utilties that I use on a daily basis.  However, my question is: How can I not repeat so much code?

For example if I have a function that gets a list of hostnames from a file, I have to create that parameter in every single function.  How can I just create it once, and then have each function prompt for it, or grab it?

```
function CopyFiles {

param (
[parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the Path to the Machine List File     (UNC Path or local). ")]
[ValidateScript({$_ -ne ""})]
[string] $MachineListFilename,

...Sometime later in the script...

$MachineList = Get-Content $MachineListFilename

}

function DoSomeOtherTask {

    param (
[parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the Path to the Machine List File     (UNC Path or local). ")]
[ValidateScript({$_ -ne ""})]
[string] $MachineListFilename,

...Sometime later in the script...

$MachineList = Get-Content $MachineListFilename

}
```

It just seems really in-efficient to cut and paste the same code over and over again.  Especially for something like, domain-name, username, password, etc.

Ultimately, I'm trying to get to a point to where I just write wrapper scripts for these functions once I import the module.  Then I can just pass parameters via the command line.  However, with the current way I'm doing it, the module is going to be littered with a lot of repetitive code, like parameters for username and password, etc.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Make your cmdlets/functions as independent and flexible as you can. Sometimes a wrapper function is the way to go, other times consolidating things into one function and calling it differently is more workable.

In the example you've given here, give the caller two options - you can pass in the filename for the list of machines, or pass in the list of machines. That way, you can read the file once in the calling script, and pass the array of machine names into each function. This will be **much** more efficient as you're only reading from disk one time.

I strongly recommend reading up on [advanced functions](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=powershell+advanced+functions) and [parametersets](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=powershell+parameterset) to simplify things (you'll need this for my suggestion above).

As for "repetitive code" - as soon as you find yourself copying/pasting code, **stop**. Find a way to make that code generic and move it into its own function, then call that function wherever it's needed. This isn't a PowerShell notion - this is standard programming, the [DRY Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Even then, you'll still find yourself with some modicum of copypasta. It's going to happen just because of the nature of the PowerShell environment. Look at Microsoft's own cmdlets - you'll see evidence of it there too. The key is to *minimize* it.

Having 3 cmdlets that all take username & password (why not take a `Credential` object instead/as another option, BTW?) **will** result in copying & pasting those parameters in the function definition. You're not going to avoid that, and it's not necessarily a bad thing. You can create code snippets in most good editors (PowerShell ISE included) to automatically "generate" it for you if that makes it easier/faster.

Comment: Thanks.  For starters I am going to try and declare things like username, password, etc. at the top of the module so that hopefully that can be shared between all the functions.  Of course when I import the module it may prompt me for it... which could get cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to create intermediary functions that call my functions with specific parameters for things I do a lot of times.  I manage these with a switch statement.  This way, the backend driver does not change, and I have a nice interface I can give to others who want to use, but not develop on, the code I made.

```
function frontEnd {
    call intermediary(typeA)
}

function intermediary (callType){
    switch(callType){
        case(typeA):
            call backEnd(param1="get dns" param2="domain1" param3=True
        case(typeB):
            call backEnd(param1="add to dns" param2="domain" param3=False
        case(other):
            call backEnd(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}
```

Depending on what functionality you are looking for, this could help you.  This is a very crude way of doing it, and I highly suggesting making it more robust and stable if you aren't going to be the only one using it.